# android alarm app - Receiver isn't starting

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Iv'e been trying to make a timed notifacation and it's just not working, help?

setting the alarm:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,0);

          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);  //calendar is declared and taking it's values from a time picker
```

Receiver:

```
   public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

       Log.wtf("ddd", "IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII");

       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       context.startService(service1);



    }   
}
```

manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name="MyAlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="REFRESH_THIS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: provide what error are you getting through logcat !

Comment: AlarmManager.RTC, try changing it to AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: Have you double checked that you are getting the expected values for `calendar`?

Comment: actually I'm getting this number: 1380312900161 when I try to set alarm to a minute from now, but, when I try to enter 60000 insted of calendar.getTimeInMillis() the alarm starts imidatelly

Answer (score 0):

did you add the alarm setting permission in the manifest ?

[SET_ALARM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ALARM)

```
"com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"
```